# How can I change semaphore and shared memory values?

Tags: bash, kernel

I am new to Ubuntu Linux.

How can I change semaphore and shared memory values? What calculations do I use to work out what I should change them to? I need to set the values for backup operations.

I am using CommVault software for backup operations. My current semaphore values are 32000 1024000000 500 32000, which are not enough to take backup. I have to change the values to allow the backup operation.

Comment: That is a question better suited for SO since this is about the kernel and not about the operating system. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359322/how-to-share-semaphores-between-processes-using-shared-memory

Comment: Maybe [cs.stackexchange]

Comment: It's an end user issue so no need to send to [SO].

Comment: As @Zanna says, this is about system administration, not software development. [That SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8359322) is about writing C code; this question is not. (See [the answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/908346/22949).) Activities like [putting a `kernel.sem` entry in `sysctl.conf`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Setting_Semaphores-Setting_Semaphore_Parameters.html) are fully within the scope of Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the values of semaphores and shared memory with command:

```
ipcs -a
```

You can change them with command:

```
sysctl
```

(and by making changes in `/etc/sysctl.conf`)

You can check [this page](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3664772) for more info about making these changes

Below is an extract from [CommVault documentation](http://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v10/article?p=products/unix/kernel_parameters.htm) about setting shared memory:

> The minimum recommended value for the SEMMNI parameter is 128. Use the
>   following formula to calculate the value for the SEMMSL parameter:
>   Non-MediaAgent: SEMMSL = 1 * number_of_desired_streams MediaAgent:
>   SEMMSL = 12 * number_of_desired_streams Use the following formula to
>   calculate the value for the SEMMNS parameter: SEMMNS = SEMMSL * SEMMNI
>   The SEMOPM and SEMMSL parameter values must be equal. If any
>   applications or databases are running on the client, the parameters
>   must be increased accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, can you please guide me, how to calculate the values, I need to change the values to  allow backup, currently my semaphore values are 32000 1024000000 500 32000, these values are not enough to take backup, can you please guide me, thanks.

Comment: Please provide in your question the software which you use for backup because I have my doubts about backup<->semaphors/shm usage

Comment: @Rasool, you can check my updated answer with link to the original product documentation